# Make eventlistener loop through buttons array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, event-listener

Here is my HTML and Javascript code, and basically as you can see currently what it does is show/hide a row of 3 images upon button click.
Thing is, that there are another 2 rows just like this one and I need to know how I can change the javascript code to make the show/hide thing work for all of them.
I know it has something to do with looping through an array of buttons, but I have no idea of Javascript.
Here it is :

```
<style>
    .show-tapas{
        display: none;
    }
    .show-tapas.showing{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="load-more-button">
                    <a href="#">Tapas</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row show-tapas">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="images/menu_tapas_1_1.jpeg" data-lightbox="image-1"><div class="thumb">   
                    <div class="portfolio-item">  
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="images/menu_tapas_1_0.jpeg">
                        </div>
                    </div>                 
                </a>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="images/menu_tapas_2_1.jpeg" data-lightbox="image-1"><div class="thumb"> 
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="images/menu_tapas_2_0.jpeg">
                        </div>
                    </div></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="images/menu_tapas_3_1.jpeg" data-lightbox="image-1"><div class="thumb">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="images/menu_tapas_3_0.jpeg">
                        </div>
                    </div></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
<script>
    var a = document.querySelector('.load-more-button');
    var b = document.querySelector('.show-tapas');
    a.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault
        b.classList.contains("showing") ? b.classList.remove("showing") : b.classList.add("showing");
    })
</script>
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Try using document.querySelectorAll() . Check this for more infor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

In this code I only see one row with the class `.show-tapas`.

Anyway, you should use `querySelectorAll` to take every matched items.

```
var button = document.querySelector('.load-more-button');
var tapas = document.querySelectorAll('.show-tapas');
button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    tapas.forEach(b => $(b).toggle());
})
```

Pro-tip: If you have JQuery you might consider using `$(b).toggle()` instead of `b.classList.contains("showing") ? b.classList.remove("showing") : b.classList.add("showing");`

Comment: Alright, so I just tried it out and it kind of works. I have the other two rows the same .show-tapas class and when I press the first "button", all 3 rows get hidden. On the other hand, the other 2 buttons dont do anything. I believe this would have something to do with all of them having the same class names, what should I change so that every row of photos hide separately depending on the button?